# Point sets with tangents through every point

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs, incidence-geometry

Let $D=(P,L)$ be either a $(v,k,\lambda)$-design or a near-linear space (or, more generally, any incidence structure with "points" and sets of points which are called "blocks" or "lines") and let $S \subseteq P$ be a set of points in $D$.

If $B \in L$ is a block of $D$ and $B \cap S=\{x\}$ then we say that **$B$ is tangent to $S$ at $x$**.

I am looking for information about sets with following property:

> (Ore Property) For every point $ x \in S$ there exists a tangent to
>   $S$ at $x$.

Have such sets been studied?

WHAT I KNOW SO FAR:

I think that this is a weakening of the oval property since I do not require the points to lie on an arc. Apparently there are semiovals which dispense with the arc condition but also require a unique tangent, which is still too strict. So are these

P.S. Just to be sure, I made up the name of the property, for certain good reasons.

Comment: I think the present wording is unclear.  Is this a property of S, B, or D? (I'm guessing S.)

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Of $S$.

Comment: You probably know this already, but $S$ has your Ore property whenever $S$ is contained in a proper flat, and also whenever $P$ is large relative to (quadratic in?) $S$.

Comment: @PeterDukes Actually, I don't so happy to learn something new! :) But how do you define a flat in a general design?

Comment: Flats are also known as subdesigns, or subspaces.  By the way, I am interested in designs such that any "small" collection of points is contained in a proper flat/subdesign.  They exist with surprising abundance, not just in affine or projective space of high dimension.  There are lots of tangents in these cases.

Comment: Every minimal blocking set in $PG(2,q)$ has this property, i.e, point sets which intersect every line, do not contain any line, and are minimal with respect to inclusion. This is because if there is a point $x$ in such a minimal blocking set through which there is no tangent, then you can just remove this point $x$ to get a proper subset of the blocking set which is also a blocking set.